# flash as3.0 mouse click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm trying to make a button in AS3.0, and I want it to be activated ON CLICK, not ON RELEASE..

For now I have used "MouseEvent.CLICK" and what it basically does is that it activates the button after I'm releasing/taking off the finger from mouse. And I want it to be activating when I'm pressing on it.

I need this for the application on Android, the thing is that when I touch the button on the screen, it's not reacting UNTIL I take off my finger.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an event called MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN